# CSS: Positioning an icon level with text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following styles, which implement the desired effect  of the "icon" sitting horizontally level with "MAIN TEXT" - however, I want my "MAIN TEXT" to have a spacing of 12px to "Item one". Currently the 12px starts at the bottom of the icon, which is bigger than the heading. Can anyone advise how to keep the icon level with the heading whilst being able to define spacings between the heading & item one?

```css
.container {
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #da291c;
   background: rgba(218,41,28,0.06);
   padding: 1.25rem;
}

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.063rem;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    MAIN TEXT
    <div class="icon"></div> 
  </div>  
  <ul class="list">Item one</ul>
</div>
```

I had tried to set the icon outside of the label, but this was the only way I could keep them horizontally aligned.

DESIRED OUTCOME:

Container should have `1.25rem` padding around all sides - with "Item one" sitting exactly 12px below "MAIN TEXT"

meanwhile the icon should be aligned with "MAIN TEXT" and not it & "Item one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix is to set the height as `height: 0.75rem;` for `label` that equal the `font-height` of the text & let the icon overflow.

```css
.container {
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #da291c;
   background: rgba(218,41,28,0.06);
   padding: 1.25rem;
}

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.063rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    MAIN TEXT
    <div class="icon"></div> 
  </div>  
  <ul class="list">Item one</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'have modified a little your code.
I set flex to your container and put the icon outside of label.

```css
.container {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #da291c;
  background: rgba(218, 41, 28, 0.06);
  padding: 1.25rem;
  /* add */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.063rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
 
}

.list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    MAIN TEXT
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Item one</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see the thinking, but this solution then un-do's horizontal alignment of the icon to the "MAIN TEXT"

Comment: I've update the answer, i removed  align-self: flex-end; from icon class

Comment: this solution means that the icon is level with "MAIN TEXT" and "Item one" which is not the desired result.

Comment: Can you update the question with an image of the desired result?

Comment: Don't have an image but hopefully that makes it more clear. Essentially trying to "ignore" the extra space the icon takes up and position "Item one" 12px below "MAIN TEXT" regardless of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do :)

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #da291c;
   background: rgba(218,41,28,0.06);
   padding: 1.25rem;
}


.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.063rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.list {
  padding-top: 12px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    MAIN TEXT
    <ul class="list">Item one</ul> 
   </div>
    
    <div class="icon"></div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: I hope you're not having a seizure. Many solutions are simple to implement, and the solution is different if you take a look at it! You dont have to be the center of attention mate